# Arranging pages in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, excel, export, ssrs-2008

I have a report which i am working on for work and i have an issue which might seem plain and simple to some but i really need help. I created a drill down report using a SQL table for my query, i used months for the pages because i need each month to be on a separate tab when the report is pulled in excel but now i am faced with two problems, first issue i have is the report pulls out the months in alphabetical other but i would much rather have them go from the current month (under tab 1) going backwards or if that's not possible i would like to have them ordered from January to December, my second issue is i would like to have the tabs named when the report is exported in excel. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sorting your report data by

`=MonthName(Month(Fields!DateColumnName.Value))`,

if so, change your sort expression to

`=Fields!DateColumnName.Value`